# Gnuplot 3d graph Z axis label misplaced

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to export the following script to a png picture:

```
set xlabel "Monitoring Period (sec)"
set xrange [0:60]
set ylabel "Handover Size"
set yrange [0:40]
set zlabel "Handover Time (sec)"
set zrange [0:70]

set pm3d
set term png
set output "HandOverTLengthOfMonPerHandOverSize.png"
splot "handoverTime_lenOfMonPer_HandoverSize.txt" using 1:2:3 notitle
```

A sample of data is the following:

```
0 10 1.23
5 10 6.78
10 10 12.01
15 10 15.82
20 10 22
25 10 26.53
30 10 31.78
35 10 36.9
40 10 42.69
45 10 48.9
50 10 51.2
55 10 59.1
60 10 62.39
0 20 2.01
5 20 7.99
10 20 14.71
15 20 17.24
20 20 26.91
25 20 26.42
30 20 31.97
35 20 36.9
40 20 43.18
45 20 49.01
50 20 52.01
55 20 63.41
60 20 67.82
0 30 2.01
5 30 9.22
10 30 15.24
15 30 18.56
20 30 27.02
25 30 28.33
30 30 33.45
35 30 39.01
40 30 45.18
45 30 55.02
50 30 54.87
55 30 60.81
60 30 62.01
0 40 1.95
5 40 10.04
10 40 15.99
15 40 19.53
20 40 28.19
25 40 28.13
30 40 34.32
35 40 40
40 40 45.99
45 40 56.72
50 40 55.83
55 40 61
60 40 62.53
```

The problem is that on the output png image the Axis labels are on the graph itself. How can I arrange them not to be on the graph, and can be properly viewed?

Thank you and sorry for the long post.

Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the labels with `set label` with `at` like this:

```
set label "Monitoring Period (sec)" at 50,-40,0
set xrange [0:60]
set label "Handover Size" at 85,0,0
set yrange [0:40]
set label "Handover Time (sec)" at -10,0,80
set zrange [0:70]

set pm3d
set term png
set output "HandOverTLengthOfMonPerHandOverSize.png"
splot "handoverTime_lenOfMonPer_HandoverSize.txt" using 1:2:3 notitle
```

You can specify the coordinated in different ways such as screen coordinates, type `help coordinates` in gnuplot for details.