# Gnuplot 3d graph, change plotting data from points to mesh-grid

Tags: gnuplot

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379237/gnuplot-3d-graph-z-axis-label-misplaced) I had, I received help for fixing the labels of my 3d graph. Since then, I have changed my gnuplot script to be like this:

```
set isosamples 40
unset key
set label "Monitoring Period (sec)" at 50,-40,0
set xrange [0:60]
set label "Handover Size" at 85,0,0
set yrange [0:40]
set label "Handover Time (sec)" at -10,0,80
set zrange [0:70]
set grid
set term postscript eps enhanced color
set output "LenMonPerHndSizeHndTime.eps"
splot "lenMonPerHndSizeHndTime.dat" using 1:2:3 notitle
```

The data stay the same with the previous question. My problem is that I want my graph to present a mesh (or grid, I am not sure how is it called) and not points, as it is now. Can 
anyone instruct me how to make it plot the data with a mesh-grid and not with points?

Thank you,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I have solved my problem with the following Gnuplot script:

```
set label "Monitoring Period (sec)" at 50,-40,0
set xrange [0:60]
set label "Handover Size" at 85,0,0
set yrange [0:40]
set label "Handover Time (sec)" at -10,0,80
set zrange [0:70]
set dgrid3d 30,30
set hidden3d
set term postscript eps enhanced
set output "lenMonPerHndSizeHndTime.eps"
splot "lenMonPerHndSizeHndTime.dat" using 1:2:3 with lines
```